# How to fill the array in the main function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I found online the following program using struct and functions.

We call a function that fills the array. Inside the function there is the for-loop that inserts the elements that the user gives.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
// student structure
struct student {
  char id[15];
  char firstname[64];
  char lastname[64];
  float points;
};

// function declaration
void getDetail(struct student *);

int main(void) {
  
  // student structure variable
  struct student std[3];
  
  // get student detail
  getDetail(std);
  
  return 0;
}

// function definition


void getDetail(struct student *ptr) {

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("Enter detail of student #%d\n", (i + 1));
    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->id);
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->firstname);
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->lastname);
    printf("Enter Points: ");
    scanf("%f", &ptr->points);
    
    // update pointer to point at next element
    // of the array std
    ptr++;
  }

}  
}
```

Is it possible to call the function "getDetail" repetitively in the main to fill the array instead of having the loop inside the function? I mean to have the for-loop in the main instead of inside the function?

I tried the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
// student structure
struct student {
  char id[15];
  char firstname[64];
  char lastname[64];
  float points;
};

// function declaration
void getDetail(struct student *);

int main(void) {
  
  // student structure variable
  struct student std[3];
  
  // get student detail 
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
printf("Enter detail of student #%d\n", (i + 1));
  getDetail(std);
}
  
  return 0;
}

// function definition


void getDetail(struct student *ptr) {

    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->id);
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->firstname);
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->lastname);
    printf("Enter Points: ");
    scanf("%f", &ptr->points);
    
    // update pointer to point at next element
    // of the array std
    ptr++;

}
```

But it seems that this doesn't work. What do I have to change?

---

In the "getDetail" function why when the input is an array we do not use the symbol "&" and when the input is not array we use it?

So why we use only "&" before ptr->points?

Which is the difference?

Comment: getDetail(std) -> getDetail(&std[i])

Comment: Did you read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) ? If allowed, compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Read the documentation of your C compiler and of your debugger. Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [*Programmez en language C*](https://www.eyrolles.com/Informatique/Livre/programmer-en-langage-c-9782212118254/)

Comment: ptr++ won't work. Function parameters are always passed by value in C. So ptr is a local variable and changing it does not change the caller's variable.

Comment: Get in the habit now of protecting against overflows.  Use `scanf("%14s", ptr->id);` and similarly on all your scanfs that use `%s`.  Also, always check the value returned by scanf to know how many conversion specifiers were matched.

Comment: I tried this and it works!!! Why do we write it like this? @kaylum

Comment: Do you mean to use s when we have characters in scanf? @WilliamPursell

Comment: @pingu I don't understand your question.  I'm suggesting that you should  always use a maximum field width with `%s`.  ie, instead of `%s` you should always use `%Ns` where N is at most one less than the size of the buffer being written.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr++;` in the `getDetail` function will update the local variable `ptr` and it will vanish on returning from the function.

Have `getDetail` do only getting detail, and have `main` switch the element to receive the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
// student structure
struct student {
  char id[15];
  char firstname[64];
  char lastname[64];
  float points;
};

// function declaration
void getDetail(struct student *);

int main(void) {
  
  // student structure variable
  struct student std[3];
  struct student* ptr = std;
  
  // get student detail 
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    printf("Enter detail of student #%d\n", (i + 1));
    getDetail(ptr);
    // update pointer to point at next element
    // of the array std
    ptr++;
  }
  
  return 0;
}

// function definition


void getDetail(struct student *ptr) {

    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->id);
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->firstname);
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->lastname);
    printf("Enter Points: ");
    scanf("%f", &ptr->points);

}
```

Comment: I understand!!! In the "getDetail" function why when the input is an array we do not use the symbol "&" and when the input is not array we use it?

So why we use only "&" before ptr->points?

Which is the difference?

Comment: Most arrays in expressions are automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so you don't have to `&` for arrays to get pointers. Actually using `&` is an exception of this automatic conversion and will yield another type, so you mustn't used `&` for arrays with `scanf()`.